# Are devas stars?

Tags: gods, astrology, cosmology

Deva means heavenly, divine, bright, shining one
Each Deva is not a permanent specific individual entity but the certain ruling position, titles each held by a reborn soul in higher dimensions that keeps changing after countless cosmic years in cycle, a pious soul replaces, takes the deva position, in endless cycle, loop.
So are Devas stars or any other galactic objects?

Comment: Not all Deva-s are stars, but all stars are deva-s (e.g. Sun). Moving in higher plane of existence, the life becomes longer & slower. We may associate rivers & mountains also with deva-s. Stars could be few of the highest forms of Devas.

Comment: Are devis, planets that revolve around a star (Deva)?

Answer (score 3):

It is revealed in Mahabharata who really are the stars.

[Mahabharata, Vana Parva: Indralokagamana Parva, SECTION XLII](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03042.htm)

After Arjuna pleased Shiva and ascended the celestial car of Indra.

> Thus having bidden farewell to the mountain, that slayer of hostile heroes--Arjuna--blazing like the Sun himself, ascended the celestial car. And the Kuru prince gifted with great intelligence, with a glad heart, coursed through the firmament on that celestial car effulgent as the sun and of extra-ordinary achievements. And after he had become invisible to the mortals of the earth, he beheld thousands of cars of extra-ordinary beauty.

Then, he saw who really were the stars.

> **And in that region there was no sun or moon or fire to give light, but it blazed in light of its own**, generated by virtue of ascetic merit. **And those brilliant regions that are seen from the earth in the form of stars**, **like lamps (in the sky)--so small in consequence of their distance, though very large--were beheld by the son of Pandu, stationed in their respective places**, full of beauty and effulgence and blazing with splendour all their own.

The stars are in reality regions due to the ascetic merit of the rishis which is why Arjuna saw them next.

> And there he beheld **royal sages crowned with ascetic success, and heroes who had yielded up their lives in battle**, and those that had **acquired heaven by their ascetic austerities, by hundreds upon hundreds**. And there were also **Gandharvas, of bodies blazing like the sun, by thousands upon thousands, as also Guhyakas and Rishis and numerous tribes of Apsaras.**

Arjuna was filled with wonder seeing many kings, rishis, Gandharvas, and Guhyakas. Then, Matali tells them that they are seen as stars from the earth.

> And beholding those self-effulgent regions, Phalguna became filled with wonder, and made enquiries of Matali. And Matali also gladly replied unto him, saying, 'These, O son of Pritha, are virtuous persons stationed in their respective places. **It is these whom thou hast seen, O exalted one, as stars, from the earth.'**